# loop param not working as expected

Tags: createjs, animate-cc, tweenjs

I have a single clip on the stage with an instance name of `testShape`. In frame 1 I have the following code:

```
createjs.Tween.get(this.testShape, {loop:true}).to({y:240}, 1000);
```

When I run this it loops infinitely as expected but what I want is for it to loop three time then stop and fire a `complete` event.
The docs say that the loop param...

> Indicates the number of times to loop. If set to -1, the tween will loop continuously.

Which suggests I should be able to set `{loop: 3}` to achieve my desired result but any number value other than 0 just causes it to loop endlessly.

Can anyone advise on what I'm doing wrong or how to make a Tween loop n times before completing?

Cheers all

Comment: What version of createjs are you using? Here is a quick fiddle with 1.0: https://jsfiddle.net/tg7oumdb/

Comment: I don't know. Whatever version comes bundled with Adobe Animate CC 15.2. I got it working in the end by making each tween set up the next as it completes. It's a bit hacky, but I'm on a deadline and it seems to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like TweenJS 0.6.2 and earlier used a [Boolean value](https://github.com/CreateJS/TweenJS/blob/0.6.2/src/tweenjs/Tween.js#L140) for `loops`, so while you can set it to `true` or `false`, you can not put it as a number of loops. If you set it to a number, it will be converted to `true`.

```
createjs.Tween.get(obj, {loop:true}).to(…).to(…);
```

This behaviour was updated in version 1.0.0 of TweenJS, in September, 2017.

```
createjs.Tween.get(obj, {loop:3}).to(…).to(…);
```

I am glad you found a solution:

> I got it working in the end by making each tween set up the next as it completes.

Comment: This makes sense. I can see now in the generated HTML that it's using 2015.11.26